# Why some apps don't work properly with "Super" + "arrows" shortcuts?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

Typically, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> (arrow) or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> move the program to the left or right of the screen and work fine with *Chrome*, *Nautilus*; but they don't work with some other programs like *LibreOffice*, *qBittorrent*, and others. However, in these last apps <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> work fine.

How I could make all apps respond well to this right and left arrow shortcuts?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I am in Ubuntu 19.04 and I do not have your problem. LibreOffice is version 6.2.7.1 and qBittorrent is version 4.1.5 (64-bit). Just FYI.